# Python - How to create new array of product sums from one array value times all values of another

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

For example, I have these two arrays:

a = [1,3,5,7,9]
b = [2,4,6]

I want to add the sum of products multiplying each value of array a by every value of array b. Ultimately resulting in a new array that would look like.

[12, 36, 60, 84, 108]

I get as far as:

```
a = [1,3,5,7,9]
b = [2,4,6]
ab = []                     
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b)):
        ab.append(a[i]*b[j])
print(ab)
```

But unsure how to add the products.

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: [sum(i*j for j in b) for i in a]

Comment: Did you mean to multiply each element in `a` with `sum(b)`?

Answer (score 2):

Why not this then:

```
[i*sum(b) for i in a]
```

**Demo:**

```
a = [1,3,5,7,9]
b = [2,4,6]
print([i*sum(b) for i in a])
```

Output:

```
[12, 36, 60, 84, 108]
```

Comment: Aha, `a * x + a * y + a * z = a * (x + y + z)`!

Comment: @slider Yeah, :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
[sum(i*j for j in b) for i in a]
#[12, 36, 60, 84, 108]
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to multiply each element in a with sum(b)? This code will do it for you.

```
a = [1,3,5,7,9]
b = [2,4,6]
b_sum = sum(b)
ab = [x * b_sum for x in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory numpy solution

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,3,5,7,9])
b = np.array([2,4,6])
np.sum(a[:,None]*b[None,:], axis=1)
```

Output

```
array([ 12,  36,  60,  84, 108])
```